# How to get an Html code of an Icon in GWT

Tags: gwt

I'm trying to get an Html code of an Icon. I have tried using get InnerHtml but the output was null.

```java
Icon plus = newIcon();
plus.setType(IconType.PLUS);
plus.getElement().getStyle().setFontSize(13, Unit.PX);
String ic =plus.getElement().getInnerHTML();
GWT.log("HTML: "+ic);
```

Expected Output:

```java
<i class="fa fa-plus" style="font-size: 13px;"></i>`
```

Comment: Which UI lib are you using?

Comment: Appointment Widget

Comment: And Appointment widget is part of?

Comment: I have created the widget under a calendar panel.

Comment: Anyhow thanks i got the logic i used the method .toString